# Run functions in parallel

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to run **parallel programmed functions** in **PowerShell**?

Something like:

```
Function BuildParallel($configuration)
{
    $buildJob = {
        param($configuration)
        Write-Host "Building with configuration $configuration."
        RunBuilder $configuration;
    }

    $unitJob = {
        param()
        Write-Host "Running unit."
        RunUnitTests;
    }

    Start-Job $buildJob -ArgumentList $configuration
    Start-Job $unitJob

    While (Get-Job -State "Running")
    {
        Start-Sleep 1
    }

    Get-Job | Receive-Job
    Get-Job | Remove-Job
}
```

Does not work because it complains about not recognizing "RunUnitTests" and "RunBuilder", which are functions declared in the same script file. Apparently this happens because the script block is a new context and does not know anything about the scripts declared in the same file.

I could try to use **-InitializationScript** in Start-Job, but both RunUnitTests and RunBuilder call more functions declared in the same file or referred from other files, so...

I'm sure there's a way to do this, since it's just modular programming (functions, routines and all that stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the functions in a separate file and import them into the current context wherever needed via dot sourcing. I do this in my Powershell profile, so some of my custom functions are available.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem "$PSprofilePath\functions"
$items | ForEach-Object {
    . $_.FullName
}
```

If you wanted import one file, it would just be:

```
. C:\some\path\RunUnitTests.ps1
```

Comment: But should I use that inside the ScriptBlock and functions will be automatically recognized?

Comment: Correct, the ScriptBlock/job is runs in it's own context, so you would run it at the start of each scriptblock to import your functions into that job's context.